# Angular: Observable changes behavior when using a pipe and tab

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular10

I am working with Angular 10 and got the problem that the completion behavior of my observable changes, depending on wether I use a pipe or not. Here are the two relevant parts of my code.

**auth.service.ts**

```js
...
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
register(email: string, password: string): Observable<RegistrationResponse> {
    return this.http.post<RegistrationResponse>(
      `${environment.API_URL}/users/register`,
      { email, password }).pipe(tap<RegistrationResponse>({
        next: (data) => {
          console.log('success - tap');
          if (data.jwt !== undefined) {
            this.setSession(data.jwt);
          }
        },
        error: () => {
          console.log('error - tap');
        }
      })
    );
}
...
```

**auth.component.ts**

```js
...
this.authService.register(this.email, this.password).subscribe({
    next: (_) => {
      console.log('success');
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    },
    error: (error) => {
      console.log('error');
      this.error = error.error || 'Error';
      this.loading = false;
    }
});
...
```

When the requests fails and I get an error response, it causes the following output (as expected):

```
error - tap
error
```

But when the requests succeeds, I get this:

```
success - tap
error                 <--- unexpected
```

**=> How does this make sense, what am I missing?**

---

Additionally, when removing the tap pipe, the completion handler gets called as expected.

```js
register(email: string, password: string): Observable<RegistrationResponse> {
    return this.http.post<RegistrationResponse>(
      `${environment.API_URL}/users/register`,
      { email, password })/*.pipe(tap<RegistrationResponse>({
        next: (data) => {
          console.log('success - tap');
          if (data.jwt !== undefined) {
            this.setSession(data.jwt);
          }
        },
        error: () => {
          console.log('error - tap');
        }
      })
    );*/
}
```

Output:

```
success
```

Comment: `error` callback's argument isn't supposed to be empty. Try to pass it something (an underscore for eg. similar to subscription's `next`).

Comment: thx for your idea. unfortunately this doesn't change the behaviour

Comment: You'll get this behaviour if an error is thrown in your `tap` callback. So I'd guess `this.setSession(data.jwt)` throws an error.

Comment: that's it! if you create an answer I could mark it as solved! Thx a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some code in your `tap` `next` callback likely throws an error (check `this.setSession(data.jwt)`). Errors thrown in operators are caught and send as error notifications by RxJS. So the `error` callback in `subscribe` is called if an error is thrown in your `pipe` upstream.